# Wordpress WYSIWYG editor automatically adding span classes with style

Tags: wordpress, editor, tinymce, wysiwyg, html

For some reason my WYSIWYG editor in Wordpress automatically adds span classes with style when I create a bullet list with the button. It's very annoying because I want my text to be a certain size, but the span class hardcodes the style and it messes the size up.

Does anyone know how to remove this automatic adding of the span class?

This site is for a customer and he/she doesn't know how to use HTML, that is why this has to work with the WYSIWYG editor.

Help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get the same behavior when I create a bulleted list in the WordPress WYSIWYG editor - just a standard, clean unordered list. Can you give us more details on exactly when this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, and I am not copying, each time I create a list, the editor adds in the code:

the text

to the text of the list.

How can I get rid of this ?

---

I have just find a solution that works for me in that post: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/strange-behaviour-making-lists-in-the-visual-editor

If you use a child theme, just add this function to your functions.php file:

```
 /**
 * I want to use the basic 2012 theme but don't want TinyMCE to create
 * unwanted HTML. By removing editor-style.css from the $editor_styles
 * global, this code effectively undoes the call to add_editor_style()
 */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'foobar_setup', 11 );
function foobar_setup() {
  global $editor_styles;
  $editor_styles = array();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you copying and pasting the text from somewhere?  Sometimes the text will have styles in its source and the styles get carried over to the wysiwyg.  See http://tentblogger.com/copy-paste/