# Wordpress WYSIWYG editor adding <span>

Tags: wordpress, html

I want to add some txt to pages in wordpress, but whenever I do it adds `<span font-size="small" font-family="century-gothic">` to `<p>` tags (that I too am not putting in the editor).

For some reason this causes my text to turn into "font-family: times new roman" instead of Century Gothic which is what I actually want.

Is there some way to disable the WYSIWYG editor's functionality where it adds `<span>`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468117/wordpress-wysiwyg-editor-automatically-adding-span-classes-with-style

Comment: @MyJ That question is related to list items only, and it relies on disabling an entire style. No thanks.